# Exim force TLS for specific destination domain

Tags: exim, tls

I need to configure Exim to require TLS when sending emails to a specific domain.

I know that I can use

```
 hosts_require_tls = host
```

in the smtp transport. But it sounds like that requires that I set the host of the receiving mail server. I would instead like to specify the domain.

Also, if I use this, will all other hosts/domains work without TLS? Just want to confirm before I implement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the recipient ACL and use the `encrypted` condition, [see here](http://exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch40.html#SECID192).

```
deny
    domains = secure.mail.org
    ! encrypted = *
```

EDIT

To force sending encrypted mail to some domains, you can create a "required tls" transport (specifying `host_require_tls`), and then create a router for the domains you want, e.g (untested):

```
begin router

tls_router:
    driver = accept
    domains = secure.mail.com
    transport = tls_smtp

begin transport

tls_smtp:
    driver = smtp
    hosts_require_tls = *
```

Comment: I am looking to force TLS when sending emails from my server.

Answer (score 0):

`hosts_require_tls` can be a list or wild card such as `*.example.net : example.net` the same as any other list.

Reverse configuration would be `tls_hosts = *.example.net : example.net`.

Documentation for exim is at `http://www.exim.org`.  Check `host lists` in chapter 7.

Answer (score 0):

You use two Routers for remote delivery.  The first has a `domains = foo` restriction, to apply only to your domain; most options are the same as the next Router, which handles normal remote delivery.  But you also change the `transport = ...` option to `transport = remote_smtp_tls`.

You then copy the `remote_smtp` Transport, duplicating it; call the new copy `remote_smtp_tls` and in it set `hosts_require_tls = *`